# How to change indentation in JSLint edition 2015-06-22

Tags: javascript, whitespace, indentation, jslint

I write most of my JavaScript code with an indentation of 2 spaces. I'm using http://www.jslint.com for quality control. In the new version anything else but  4 space indentation is considered wrong?

In the old version http://old.jslint.com there was a indent box where the number of whitespace could be set or an directive: /*jslint indent: 2 */ could placed at the top of the script.

I would like to avoid "messy white space" and keep a 2 space indentation.

Please advise :)

Comment: JSLint is subject to this kind of change at any time according to Crockford's latest whim. You never know when formerly acceptable code will be red flagged with no option to let you ignore the complaint. I suggest [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) as a more flexible and configurable code checker.

Comment: Another option might be [ESLint](http://eslint.org/). I do not recommend JSLint due to be very opiniated (as already pointed out by Michael Geary)

Comment: Thanks! As you suggest I will probably need to change Lint tool.  But I couldn't find this question or any text explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- use jshint.com instead of jslint.com. The 'indent' option is deprecated from both jshint and jslint. However, jshint doesn't care how many spaces your code is indented (so no warning)
- if you want to continue using jslint, you can use `/*jslint white:true */` which allows any amount of indentation (however, it also ignores extraneous spaces and tabs anywhere so the following won't produce any warning `function   anony ()   {`)
- use eslint, which is newer and more modular (allows custom plugins) than jslint and jsint. Note that eslint doesn't seem to have a simple website where you can paste in code for linting, like the other two have (someone please correct me if a site does exist)